# Allocating a pool of equivalent resources to a group of threads using semaphores

Tags: multithreading, semaphore, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

I have a doubt about a concurrent programming problem. 
More specifically, we are working with the shared memory model(i.e. threads). The problem is: given a pool of N equivalent resources, there being the constraint that at a generic instant t there can only be one thread using a resource R, write a program that allocates these resources on demand to the threads that ask for them. To do this we have to use semaphores. Note that what these resources are and what the threads do with them is out of scope, the focus is on how the resources are managed and allocated. My professor gave us a C/Java-like pseudocode solution for the resources manager class:

```
class ResourcesManager {
    semaphore mutex = 1;
    semaphore availableResourcesSemaphore = N;
    boolean available[N];
    Resource resources[N];

    public ResourcesManager(){
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            available[i] = true;
            resources[N] = new Resource();
        }
    }

    public int acquireResource() {
        int i = 0;
        P(availableResourcesSemaphore);
        P(mutex);
        while(available[i]==false) i++;
        available[i] = false;
        V(mutex);
        return i;
    }

    public void releaseResource(int i) {
        P(mutex);
        available[i] = true;                     //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        V(mutex);
        V(availableResourcesSemaphore);
    }

}
```

While I see that this solution works, there is something I don't get about the releaseResource(int i) method. Why is there the need of having the line marked with the comment "HERE IS THE PROBLEM":

```
available[i] = true;
```

executed in mutual exclusion? I have thought about it and to me it looks like nothing bad happens if we do otherwise.
What I mean is that while in the original solution we have:

```
        P(mutex);
        available[i] = true;                    
        V(mutex);
```

we can replace these three lines simply with

```
available[i] = true;
```

and the solution is still correct.

Now, of course I see that mutual exclusion is needed when operating on the array "available" in the other method acquireResource(), and since the instruction

```
available[i] = true;
```

operates on the same variable it is more elegant and conceptually cleaner to operate on it in mutual exclusion too. On the other hand, as a beginner in concurrent programming, I don't think it's good to have mutual exclusion where it is not needed.

So am I right(the instruction can be executed without mutual exclusion) or am I missing something, and removing mutual exclusion causes some issues? One final note on the execution environment: it can be both uniprocessor or multiprocessor, meaning that the solution has to work for both cases. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't know enough yet about the way multi-processor machines are implemented.  Basic issue is that one processor will set the variable to *true* but another can't see that.  Modern processors use caches and write-back buffers, they contain copies of the data in memory.  You update the copy, not the memory.  There are lower-level primitives, you need a *memory barrier*.  And the bool has to be treated *volatile* and updates need to be *atomic*.  Not the tools you have right now, you only have P() and V().  Some odds these lower-level primitives will be next month's class subject.

Comment: First, thank you for the reply! But even if one processor sets the variable to true and the other one can't see that, what does it matter? What I mean is that the second processor will still see the resource as busy and therefore won't allocate it to a thread that runs on it. But if a thread is allowed to execute                                                                                                                                 P(availableResourcesSemaphore)

Comment: If it *never* sees the variable set to *true* then it just stops working of course.  A hazard on a processor with a weak memory model or a compiler that doesn't treat the bool as volatile.  In practice it tends to work anyway, it will when you try it, but it is inefficient.  Not good properties of a core scheduling algorithm.

Comment: without suspending, there's at least one available resource. Thus, the thread that runs on the second processor won't be given the resource that has just been released, but it'll get another one. After some time, the central memory updates and the released resource appears as available to all the processors.

Comment: Ok, maybe now I can see something wrong happening: what if the variable is set to true and then the subsequent V(availableResourcesSemaphore) is executed and the change on the semaphore is visible to all the processors before the change on the boolean variable. If all the resources were busy, the P() one the availableResourcesSemaphore would now let a thread go on, even if it can't find any available resource.  P.S. apologies, the last two comments were meant to be only one.